# Trying to find all possible combinations

Tags: excel

I have been trying to work through the following problem using excel and am not sure where to start, I have tried using combinations and permeation but only have a basic understanding of them, how would you guys approach solving this?

There are 6 kinds of coffee and there are 10 kinds of flavor shots and you can put one, two or three shots in each kind of coffee. Based on this, I would like to know (and list) the unique flavor combinations and how long you could go without having the same cup of coffee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple with macros.

The first thing to note is that we need *combinations* rather than *permutations.*  This is because {Kona,vanella,chocolate} is the same as {Kona,chocolate,vanilla}.

Place the 6 coffee is **A1** thru **A6**

Place the 10 flavors in **B2** thru **B11.**  Leave **B1** empty.

Enter and run the following **VBA** macro:

```
Sub CoffeeMixer()
    Dim k As Long, _
        i As Long, _
        j As Long, _
        l As Long, _
        Z As Long
    Z = 1
    For i = 1 To 10
        cf = Cells(i, 1).Value
        For j = 1 To 11
            fl1 = Cells(i, 2).Value
            For k = j+1 To 11
                fl2 = Cells(k, 2).Value
                For l = k+1 To 11
                    fl3 = Cells(l, 2).Value
                    If fl1 = fl2 Or fl1 = fl3 Or fl2 = fl3 Then
                    Else
                        Cells(Z, "C").Value = cf
                        Cells(Z, "D").Value = fl1
                        Cells(Z, "E").Value = fl2
                        Cells(Z, "F").Value = fl3
                        Z = Z + 1
                    End If
                Next l
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

This will produce the 875 samples.

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Here is a sample:

[image: xx]

.

.

**EDIT#1**

Here is the updated code:

```
Sub CoffeeMixer()
    Range("C:F").Clear
    Dim k As Long, _
        i As Long, _
        j As Long, _
        l As Long, _
        Z As Long
    Z = 1
    For i = 1 To 6
        cf = Cells(i, 1).Value
        For j = 1 To 11
            fl1 = Cells(j, 2).Value
            kk = j + 1
            If j = 11 Then kk = 11
            For k = kk To 11
                fl2 = Cells(k, 2).Value
                ll = 1 + k
                If k = 11 Then ll = 11
                For l = ll To 11
                    fl3 = Cells(l, 2).Value
                        Cells(Z, "C").Value = cf
                        Cells(Z, "D").Value = fl1
                        Cells(Z, "E").Value = fl2
                        Cells(Z, "F").Value = fl3
                        Z = Z + 1
                Next l
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Using this version, you must fill from **B1** thru **B10** and leave **B11** blank!

Comment: This is great, thank you very much for taking the time to write all of this, this seems pretty close to what i want with the exception of the results printing out with just flavor combinations, how would the macro be altered so that it shows all combinations with one type of coffee AND 1,2 or 3 flavor shots?

Comment: @Axios_Andrew I will supply an update in a little while.

Comment: Something else i just noticed is it also does not show each coffee with only one flavor shot.

Comment: If I am right, there are 1050 possibilities or 1056, if simple coffee without extra flavor is also possible. For one coffee there are 10 possibilities with 1 flavor, then 45 = `10! / (10-2)! / 2!` possibilities with 2 flavors and 120 = `10! / (10-3)! / 3!` possibilities with 3 flavors. For 6 coffees = 6*(10+45+120) = 1050.

Comment: Does this show unique flavors though.  I came up with the same results however  "c1 f1 f2 f3" and "c1 f2 f1 f3" are not unique so that would inflate the number.  I am thinking that if i can come up with a way to print the entire list even with duplicates i can come up with a second method for weeding out non unique combinations.

Comment: @Axios_Andrew I have updated the code and the startup instructions.  Tell me what you think.

Comment: This looks good, sorry for being a pest but can i throw another condition in here now?  b11 appears with doubles such as "a1 b1 b11 b11"  however none of the other flavors come up with double shots like that or triple shots "a1 b11 b11 b11".  Is there an easy way to add that to the list so that those will be added?

Comment: @Axios_Andrew  **In this version B11 MUST BE BLANK and B1 should be filled instead!**

Comment: Ah i didnt see you had changed that, is there an easy way to add double and triple shots to this list as well?

Comment: @Axios_Andrew  As coded it will add 0,1,2,3 shots. The coding prevents adding, say, two shots of *caramel,*  for example.

Answer (score 1):

Build your table like so:

```
A       B
Coffee1 Syrup1
Coffee2 Syrup2
Coffee3 Syrup3
Coffee4 Syrup4
Coffee5 Syrup5
Coffee6 Syrup6
        Syrup7
        Syrup8
        Syrup9
        Syrup10
```

For the above data, the below formula will calculate the total number of combinations:

```
=COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(B:B)
+COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(B:B)^2
+COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(B:B)^3
```

The length of time taken to try all the different combinations depends on the level of your caffeine addiction.